# VBA - How to read spreadsheet attached to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, xlsx

I have a series of .pdf's which have Excel files attached to them. I want to extract cells "A2:C" & lastline from this spreadsheet.

How do I command VBA to read the attached .xlsx and ignore the .pdf file it is attached to?

Did a lot of searching and no hits so far...

thanks

Comment: Although Excel can create PDF files it is unable to read PDF files. That's why there are actually commercial products out there to convert PDFs to Word documents or Excel files. Since VBA is only available within MS Office the language itself cannot suffice in order to read PDF files. You will need external `References...` to do so. This again depends on your Windows installation as Windows does not ship with a library to do so. I (personally) am not aware of a free product which offers a library which you can call from within VBA.